# Ingress controller in GCP taking very long to come up

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-ingress

My ingress controller in GCP is taking more than 5 minutes for its backends to from status "unknown" to "HEALTHY", despite the fact that the pod for it has been running for almost an hour and is healthy.

Not sure what to do here. Is there a way to make this faster?

```
Every 2.0s: kubectl describe ing                                                                          Jorges-MacBook-Pro.local: Tue Jul 30 14:59:43 2019

Name:             leadgenie-django-ingress-gce
Namespace:        default
Address:          34.98.95.64
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (10.0.2.11:8080)
TLS:
  tls-leadgenie terminates staging-app.leadgenie.ai
Rules:
  Host                      Path  Backends
  ----                      ----  --------
  staging-app.leadgenie.ai
                            /    leadgenie-django-service:80 (<none>)
                            /*   leadgenie-django-service:80 (<none>)
Annotations:
  ingress.kubernetes.io/forwarding-rule:             k8s-fw-default-leadgenie-django-ingress-gce--1c2d0d85b16beb9a
  ingress.kubernetes.io/https-forwarding-rule:       k8s-fws-default-leadgenie-django-ingress-gce--1c2d0d85b16beb9a
  ingress.kubernetes.io/https-target-proxy:          k8s-tps-default-leadgenie-django-ingress-gce--1c2d0d85b16beb9a
  ingress.kubernetes.io/url-map:                     k8s-um-default-leadgenie-django-ingress-gce--1c2d0d85b16beb9a
  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:  {"apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{"kubernetes.io/ingress.c
lass":"gce","kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name":"leadgenie-staging"},"name":"leadgenie-django-ingress-gce","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"rules":
[{"host":"staging-app.leadgenie.ai","http":{"paths":[{"backend":{"serviceName":"leadgenie-django-service","servicePort":80},"path":"/"},{"backend":{"service
Name":"leadgenie-django-service","servicePort":80},"path":"/*"}]}}],"tls":[{"hosts":["staging-app.leadgenie.ai"],"secretName":"tls-leadgenie"}]}}

  ingress.kubernetes.io/backends:               {"k8s-be-30886--1c2d0d85b16beb9a":"Unknown","k8s-be-31152--1c2d0d85b16beb9a":"Unknown"}
  ingress.kubernetes.io/target-proxy:           k8s-tp-default-leadgenie-django-ingress-gce--1c2d0d85b16beb9a
  kubernetes.io/ingress.class:                  gce
  kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name:  leadgenie-staging
  ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-cert:               k8s-ssl-50ffff0cd920c11b-6cc9f460acef62eb--1c2d0d85b16beb9a
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age    From                     Message
  ----    ------  ----   ----                     -------
  Normal  ADD     6m13s  loadbalancer-controller  default/leadgenie-django-ingress-gce
  Normal  CREATE  5m11s  loadbalancer-controller  ip: 34.98.95.64
```

Comment: Assuming you are using GKE, in that case it would make sense to reach out to official GCP support for further assistance with it, cause GCE Ingress Controller's Pod runs on Master node (not accessible to you), where reside potentially meaningful information (logs, events) on the creation progress of Cloud resources behind single Ingress resource, as explained on GCE-Ingress OSS project here:
https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/blob/master/docs/faq/gce.md#what-are-the-cloud-resources-created-for-a-single-ingress

Comment: On the other hand maybe the fault is purely with the failing for some reason Managed Instance Group health-checks. Have you checked the quota limits for BACKEND_SERVICES and HEALTH_CHECKS ?
https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/blob/master/docs/faq/gce.md#the-ingress-controller-events-complain-about-quota-how-do-i-increase-it